# Migrate from CharField to LocalizedCharField

Tags: python, django, localization, django-migrations

I am integrating django-localized-fields and have to save current data in char field at least in default language.

For example:

```py
from django.db import models

class FineModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

needs to migrate to

```py
from localized_fields.models import LocalizedModel
from localized_fields.fields import LocalizedCharField

class FineModel(LocalizedModel):
    title = LocalizedCharField(blank=True, null=True, required=False)
```

and text from title column should be transferred to updated title column like that:

```py
new_obj.title.en = old_obj.title
```

I tried to add new temporary field **title_l** and use 3 migrations to

1. transfer all data from **title** field to **title_l** field
2. delete **title** field
3. rename **title_l** to **title** and delete **title_l** from model

but this is not working, because first of these migrations will fail on production contour because **title_l** is not presented in **FineModel**.

Any advices appreciated, I believe this can be done in single migration.

Comment: Your approach is correct and I am not sure why it would fail. You need to make sure you do step 1 on production *before* steps 2 and 3.

Comment: I hoped to avoid any steps on production before everything is well tested on develop server, I decided not to delete temporary field until production update

Comment: If you database system doesnt support rollbacks - you can instead make a copy of your data using the `dumpdata` command - in case you need to revert and restore the data. But you should also be able to simply change the field type without any of the steps so long as their is no incompatibility between the data types.